# add three different values ​from three dictionaries in python

Tags: dictionary

```
dict_1 = {"a":5 ,"b":8 ,"c":12}
dict_2 = {"a":10 ,"b":14 ,"c":20}
dict_3 = {"a":15 ,"b":20 ,"c":28}
```

1.now i have three different words in a txt file example in order

abc

cba

bca

I want the result of the addition to be written with the values ​​corresponding to the letters in the dictionary I showed above.

so the result is  first word "abc" = 47 (5+14+28)

second word
"cba" = 41 (12+14+15)

third word
"bca"= 43 (8+20+15)

using the first dictionary for the first letter of the word, the second dictionary for the second letter, and the third dictionary for the third letter.
how can i do this using python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. In the same working directory as the notebook, I've created a text file `data.txt` which looks like this:

```
abc
cba
bca
ab
a
abcd
```

Here is where to store the file `data.txt`

```
import os
file_path = os.getcwd()
print(file_path)    #this is where to store the file "data.txt"
```

After that, I've created a reference dictionary `ref_dict`:

```
ref_dict = {
    0: {'a': 5, 'b': 8, 'c': 12, 'd': 4},
    1: {'a': 10, 'b': 14, 'c': 20, 'd': 4},
    2: {'a': 15, 'b': 20, 'c': 28, 'd': 4},
    3: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
}

with open('data.txt') as f:
    words = f.readlines()
    for word in words:
        total = 0
        word = word.strip()
        for i, letter in enumerate(word):
            total += ref_dict[i][letter]
        print(word, total)

Output:

abc 47
cba 41
bca 43
ab 19
a 5
abcd 51
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply it really worked
So how can we do this for the lines in the txt file i.e. to calculate the word in each line in the txt?
In addition, the number of letters in each line in txt is different, I get an error when I try a two-digit word in the code you wrote.
Some of the words in the lines in the txt file are two-letter and some are three-letter.

Comment: I will try with a text file "data.txt", give me 15min

Comment: Thank you again for taking the time to answer my question, you are a real hero.